# OData: Posts query returns error

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Repro: Open https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Posts

Observe:

> The 'PostTypeId' property on 'Post' could not be set to a 'Byte' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.

Comment: man this odata stuff is a nightmare to debug ... I spent two hours the other day just finding out a semicolumn was missing somewhere

Comment: @waffles Do you want a hand?

Comment: @waffles This is what happens when you write useful things; that's why I make sure all my apps suck

Comment: @Pavel It's open source: http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: @Pavel, sure ... any help would be handy :)

Comment: @waffles Please check my patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, [this patch](http://code.google.com/r/pchuchuva-local-sede/source/detail?r=84b246dfd6d95995104fc692c6ff50510b0c7847) should fix it.

Comment: I pulled the change ... but somehow broke my build ... will deploy this first thing next week